# Responsive Youtube

Tags: html, css, youtube

So I'm trying to get an embedded youtube clip on my page. Every site I look on seems to tell me something like this is the answer:

HTML

```
<div class="video-container"><iframe.......></iframe></div>
```

CSS

```
.video-container {
        position:relative;
        padding-bottom:56.25%;
        padding-top:30px;
        height:0;
        overflow:hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
}
```

However I don't want the video to take up the whole screen. When I put a height and width on it in the html code that doesn't seem to solve it. So I tried changing the height and width from 100% to 75% that made the video smaller but the outside video-container was still taking up the full width space.

Comment: Have you tried putting a width on the `video-container` rather than the `iframe`?

Comment: @Blake Mann yes, it "crops" the video.

Comment: Adding a max-width to the `video-container` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your `video-container` in another div and setting the width on that outer div.

To modify your example:

```
<div id="video-wrapper">
  <div class="video-container">
    <iframe></iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS for `video-wrapper`:

```
#video-wrapper {
  width: 75%;
}
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/c34phqgo/